# Running MStest in cruise control .net build server

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, mstest

I'm trying to setup cruisecontrol.net to work with our existing projects.

The projects use the visual studio 2008 testing tools (running as .net 2.0).

During the actual build process I get several error messages, most or which are:

Type 'TestClass' is not defined.

I'm assuming that this is because I don't have the testing framework installed on my build server.

I'd rather not just copy bits from my dev machine (that always feels a bit hacky) and I'd also rather not install visual studio on the build sever (that seems like overkill).

Does anyone know where I can get a standalone installer to put these files on my build server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSTest requires Visual Studio.  You'll need to install it on your build machine (or use a more lightweight testing framework!)

Comment: Yes either install vsts, or copy over just the needed bits.

Comment: In the end I installed VS 2008. I'm starting to see why people have problems with MSTest.

Answer (score 8):

You can get hold of the MSTest.exe and associated libraries on a redistributable disk image under the title of "[Visual Studio Agents](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1334)".

Instructions:

1. Download and run setup from the disk
2. Run the test agent installer
3. No need to install the agent as a service or configure the test agent as you just want to run it from the command line.
4. The MSTest tool will now be installed somewhere like "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE" which is the same path as for visual studio.

Comment: This is the link for vs2013 - I installed this on a 2008r2 server and our project started to build again. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40750